# Chain rule for total derivatives

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Suppose I have two functions $f:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and$ g: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$

The latter given by $t \rightarrow p+t(x-p)$.

Why is the derivative of the composition

$\sum_{k=0}^{n} (x_{k}-p_{k})\frac{\delta f}{\delta x_{k}}(p+t(x-p))$?

I been looking at the total derivative chain rule but cannot make sense of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $h(t):= f(g(t))$ with $x$ fixed, then $h(t)=f(p+t(x-p)).$ By the chain rule we get

$$h'(t)=f'(p+t(x-p)) \cdot g'(t),$$

where $ \cdot$  denotes the usual inner product on $ \mathbb R^n.$

We have $g'(t)=x-p.$ Can you proceed ?